# JC Decaux HTTP API Request with Hurl.it

Tags: api, http

I would like to get data about city bikes - Dublin bikes- a bike sharing scheme run by JC Decaux. The information is available in real time from their website via an API. I have never gotten information from an API and cannot seem to work it.

I am using hurl.it just to check the structure of what I am requesting. I am attempting to get a list of the stations as denoted here: (https://developer.jcdecaux.com/#/opendata/vls?page=dynamic)

With this HTTP request:

```
GET https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
```

I have put

```
https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations&apiKey={apikey} HTTP/1.1
```

into the "Destination" field. and "Accept" and "application/json" into the two "Header" fields.

I have tried many variations of this and nothing is giving me anything other than a 404 Not Found response. I am using an actual key for the api key after signing up.

Am I using this hurl.it site correctly?

Comment: You have got a valid API key and are sending it instead of {apikey}?

Comment: Dont put `HTTP/1.1` in the URL

Comment: @AlexK. Yes I have a valid API key. Should I leave in the curly brackets? I have tried without the curly brackets with the "HTTP/1.1" removed and still 404 error.

Comment: You should most likely remove them

Comment: @AlexK. Tried removing them, no joy, Do you use this hurl.it tool to test API's? IS there another way I could do this simply?

Comment: I tried it on hurl.it - seems you must click the not-a robot-thing else it confusingly just pops up "Bad Request"

Comment: You have & but for the first paramater you need ? so `https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/contracts?apiKey=BLABLA` - on hurl.it I get
`"error": "Unauthorized"` which is good and expected as its a json response and I dont have an API key.

Comment: You use the  `stations` url but the api docs show to use that you need to give a "contract" paramater so it would be 
`https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=WHATEVER_THIS_IS&apiKey=BLABLA`

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks got it now using https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=WHATEVER_THIS_IS&apiKey=BLABL‌​A             Is it just me or was that not very clear that .../v1/stations&apiKey alone would not work?

Comment: The & instead of ? broke the url. In your linked page under *Get the stations of a contract* it shows `contract={contract_name}` so thats how I knew.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get an API Key. Go to 
https://developer.jcdecaux.com
to get one.

You can use your key in the URL like so: https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=dublin&apiKey=yourapikey